# Would the author most certainly be talking about a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$/$\mathbb{C}$ here?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am working on the following problem in Serg Lang's Linear Algebra book:

> In the vector space of functions, what is the function satisfying the condition VS2?

For reference VS2 is:

> There is an element of V, denoted by 0, such that 0 + u = u + 0 = u
>   for all elements u of V.

It is frustrating that he does not say what field the vector space is over, especially since just a few pages back, he says:

> Thus when dealing
>   with vector spaces, we shall always specify the field over which we take
>   the vector space.

Now I would think that the answer would be $f(x) = 0$. But that seems to be assuming that the vector space of functions is over $\mathbb{C}$/$\mathbb{R}$/$\mathbb{Q}$. Is it reasonable to assume that?

Comment: There is no need to assume this is over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb Q$, one can talk about functions with values in another field.

Comment: You are correct, it's the zero function. Whenever $V$ and $W$ are $F$-vector spaces then the collection of all linear transformations between them is an $F$-vector space. Here the "zero vector" is the zero function.

Comment: Why don't you assume the field $\mathbb F$ (the range of values of the functions) is arbitrary and the domain is an arbitrary set $X$, so all functions are from $X$ to $\mathbb F$, and answer the question that way?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Good point.

Comment: This boils down to what the term "function" refers to if not specified. Some would say that function (in contrast to map) withoout additional specification of domain and range would mean that both domain and range are $\mathbb R$ ...

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any need to "pin-down" the field, or "assume" anything about the field, save for the fact that given $V$ is a vector space, it *is* defined over *some* field.

You need only provide a function that satisfies the given axiom, regardless of there being no specified field. Indeed, the function you suggest, $f(x) = 0$ works quite nicely.

*However*, since we are talking about the vector space of *functions*, strictly speaking, the italicized term "functions" does suggest that the field in question is $\mathbb R$. So I don't think you'd be terribly penalized (if at all) for making this assumption, provided you explicitly state how you are interpreting the term "function" (as in *real-valued* functions whose domain and range is the set of real numbers).

Comment: Especially, when verifying VS2, there is no reference to a field (it is just part of "$V$ is an abelian group")

Comment: Indeed, Hagen. You beat me to my edit!

Comment: So as for the answer, I would think that I could say: "Since $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ and $F$ is a group, let $o$ be $f(x) = \mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the additive identity of $F$. So then would I need to verify that $o + u = u + o = u$ for all functions $u$?

Comment: Yes, but there's not much to be said there, since $(u+o)(x)=u(x)+o(x)=u(x)+0=u(x)$.